# HTTP POST works with www but not without it

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, http, http-post

HTTP requests from iphone to webservice script works when its called to http://www.my-domain.com/webservices/function , But Values are not getting POSTed to webservice script when just http://my-domain.com/webservices/function is used. What could be reason ? GET method works in both the cases.

Comment: Have you verified that when using `www` you are actually getting posted values? I can't imagine the subdomain would have any effect on this.

Comment: Do you have force www redirect in your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I verified. When using www print_r($_POST) gives the array of post values , Else its prints just an empty array().

Comment: Yeah, but if you type my-domain.com in your browser without the www are you automatically being redirected to www.my_domain.com?

Comment: @Quasdunk Yes , I have. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: I guess so. Because you can take the query string while redirecting, but not the post data. That's why GET works but POST does not.